# Pass HTML element to div like string

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to pass HTML text to my `div`, I need this string rendered as HTML elements, My code:

```
<div id="divchat" style="width: 500px; height: 300px; border: 2px solid brown;"/></div>
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.msj) 
<button type="submit" id="btnSend">Send</button>

<script>
    $(function(){
          var chatNS = '@HttpContext.Current.Application["Chateo"].ToString()';
          $("#divchat").append(chatNS);
    });
</script>
```

`div` is showing content just like a string, how could I get HTML elements to be rendered correctly into `divchat`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried wrapping your `HttpContext.Current.Application["Chateo"]` in `@Html.Raw()`?

```
<script>
    $(function(){
      var chatNS = '@Html.Raw(HttpContext.Current.Application["Chateo"])';
      $("#divchat").append(chatNS);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It Works! :) I'm new and i can't give you points now, but Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Even better abstract the call to Current.Application out into a class and have this property return an MvcHtmlString to prevent the need for @Html.Raw() AND ensure you can easily change the mechanism by which this string is cached/accessed in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#divchat").html(chatNS);
```

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work, using @Html.Raw() as @MassivePenguin said works for me.